# How do I use a progress bar when fechting data from online server

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, asynchronous

I am fetching data from an online server and this process takes about 2 minutes, I would like to show progress for this process.

Here is my code:

```
int ProgressBarValue{get; set;} ;

var context = await client.GetAsync(url);

if (context != null)
{
    var content = await context.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Candles>(content);
}
```

On the XAML:

```
<ProgressBar Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Height="21" 
     Width="512" Margin="0,0,11,0" Value="{Binding ProgressBarValue}"></ProgressBar>
```

Comment: Where's the equation to calculate the ProgressBarValue? There isn't much to go on here without more info. have a look at this - https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-progressbar-control/

Comment: If it's just call and wait.... Around 120 seconds then whst is going to drive any meaningful percentage done? It's often impossible to know. Which is why spinners ( aka throbbers ) are popular. In your case, 2 minutes is quite a long time to most users so i would also advise a message saying "this is likely to take a couple of minutes" or something similar. Anything over 30 seconds and a user is likely to get frustrated or assume it isn't working.

Comment: Cool. Thanks, but could you please show me an example of an equation for calculating the progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API of `HttpClient` doesn't accept a callback to report progress or to get the length of the HTTP response in advance. To know the response's length in advance is mandatory in order to be able to calculate the progress percentage.

For this reason I recommend to configure the `ProgressBar` to show continuous progress feedback:

```
<!-- Show continuous progress -->
<ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" />
```

If you want to show progress e.g., a bytes read feedback label, you have to manually read the content of the response body.

The following example reports the progress in bytes read and supports optional cancellation:

```
// Property should be a DependencyProperty (when on a control like Window)
// or raise the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event
public double ProgressValue { get; set; }

public async Task GetJsonResponse(string url)
{
  string jsonResponseText = await DownloadFromUrlWithProgressAsync(url, CancellationToken.None);

  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jsonResponseText))
  {    
    return;
  }

  var candles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Candles>(jsonResponseText);
}

private async Task<string> DownloadFromUrlWithProgressAsync(
  string url, 
  CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
  cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

  this.ProgressValue = 0;

  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    // Only read headers. Content is read later (manually)
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken))
    {
      // Report progress safely from the background thread to the UI thread
      // by using Progress<T>
      IProgress<double> progressReporter = 
        new Progress<double>(progress => this.ProgressValue = progress);

      // Read from content stream with optional cancellation support          
      var responseContent = await Task.Run(
        () => ReadResponseContentAsync(response, progressReporter, cancellationToken),
        cancellationToken);

      return responseContent;
    }
  }
}

private async Task<string> ReadResponseContentAsync(
  HttpResponseMessage response,
  IProgress<double> progressReporter,
  CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

  var responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  using (Stream responseContentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
  {
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseContentStream))
    {
      while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
      {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        // Choose a buffer size
        var buffer = new char[4096];

        await streamReader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        responseBuilder.Append(buffer);

        // Report progress in bytes read (automatically posts to the UI thread)
        double progress = responseBuilder.Length;
        progressReporter.Report(progress);
      }

      return responseBuilder.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```